# I would like to implement Modified Gram-schmidt on python

Tags: python

I would like to a function to implement Modified Gram-schmidt on python as below

```
def mgs (A):

    m,n=np.shape(A)
    Q=copy.deepcopy(A)
    R=np.zeros([n,n])
    for i in range(n-1):
        R[i,i]=np.linalg.norm(Q[:,i])
        Q[:,i]=Q[:,i]/R[i,i]
        R[i,i+1:n]=Q[:.i].T@Q[:,i+1:n]
        Q[:,i+1:n]=Q[:,i+1:n]-Q[:,i]*R[i,i+1:n]
    R[n,n]=np.linalg.norm(Q[:,n])
    Q[:,n]=Q[:,n]/R[n,n]
    return Q,R
```

But on the line : `R[i,i+1:n]=Q[:.i].T@Q[:,i+1:n]` is detected as error like SyntaxError: invalid syntax

I don't understand why this symptoms was created on python.

Comment: A guess - do you mean to use `*` to multiply terms instead of `.`?

Comment: Did you mean `Q[:,i]`? Note the comma between `:` and `i` (instead of period).

Comment: @j1-lee omg. I solve the problem. Why did I couldn't find that error :( Thank you!